# add column to data set in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add predicted data back to my original dataset in Python. I think I'm supposed to use Pandas and ASSIGN and pd.DataFrame but I have no clue how to write this after reading all the documentation (sorry I'm new to all this and just started learning coding recently). I've written my code below and just need help with the code for adding my predictions back to the dataset. Thanks for the help!

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [2, 3]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25,     
random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling X_train and X_test
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

#Feature scaling the all independent variables used to build the model
whole_dataset = sc.transform(X)

# Fitting classifier to the Training set
# Create your Naive Bayes here
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
classifier = GaussianNB()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)

# Predicting the results for the whole dataset
y_pred2 = classifier.predict_proba(whole_dataset) 

# Add y_pred2 predictions back to the dataset
???
```

Comment: I think now looking at what you're trying to do, you're misunderstanding what is happening. You've split the dataset into a train and test data. You then trained on the train dataset and then fitted on on the test data. You're then trying to assign back to the original dataset which is all the rows. For instance you have 400 rows in dataset but only 100 rows in y_pred so you can't assign different length rows back. What you want to do is `y_pred = classifier.predict_proba(X)` and then assign this back : `dataset['predict_class_1'],dataset['predict_class_2'] = y_pred[:,0],y_pred[:,1]`

Comment: Great thanks i'll try it out! :) I changed the code a little bit so it now predicts for 400 rows. I couldn't upload the datafile here but it can be downloaded at https://www.superdatascience.com/machine-learning/   section 18 naive bayes zip file. The csv file is called Social_Network_Ads.csv. I hope I can get it to work :)

Comment: @EdChum It worked! Thanks!

Comment: Sure! How do i accept ur answer to close the thread? Also, can u update ur answer to the X dataset so it's feature scaled before the predict function is applied (just in case somebody else is doing the same thing i was doing)

Comment: There's an empty tick mark at the top left of my answer, the feature scaling portion isn't pertinent to your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do `dataset['prediction'] = y_pred` to add a new column.

Pandas supports a simple syntax for adding new columns, here it will add a new column and probably take a view on the numpy array returned from sklearn so it should be nice and fast.

**EDIT**

Looking at your code and the data, you're misunderstanding what `train_test_split` does, this is splitting the data into 3/4 1/4 splits of your original dataset which has 400 rows, your X train data contains 300 rows, the test data is 100 rows. You're then trying to assign back to your original dataset which is 400 rows. Firstly the number of rows don't match, secondly what is returned from `predict_proba` is a matrix of the predicted classes as a percentage. So what you want to do after training is to predict on the original dataset and assign this back as 2 columns by sub-selecting each column:

```
y_pred = classifier.predict_proba(X)
```

now assign this back :

```
dataset['predict_class_1'],dataset['predict_class_2'] = y_pred[:,0],y_pred[:,1]
```

Comment: I tried it but then I got this error ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1. Any idea why this is happening?  Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to add raw data and code to your question in order for us to reproduce this

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions. [The answer of EdChurm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44562804/7899410) had mentioned one.
As far as I know, pandas has other 2 methods to work with it.

1. [`df.insert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)
2. [`df.assign()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

Since you didn't provide the data in use, here's a pretty simple example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), columns=['raw'])
df = df.assign(cube_raw=df['raw']**2)
df.insert(1,'square_raw',df['raw']**3)

df
          raw square_raw     cube_raw
0    1.624345   2.638498     4.285832
1   -0.611756   0.374246    -0.228947
2   -0.528172   0.278965    -0.147342
3   -1.072969   1.151262    -1.235268
4    0.865408   0.748930     0.648130
5   -2.301539   5.297080   -12.191435
6    1.744812   3.044368     5.311849
7   -0.761207   0.579436    -0.441071
8    0.319039   0.101786     0.032474
9   -0.249370   0.062186    -0.015507
```

Just keep in mind that `df.assign()` doesn't work inplace, so you should reassign to your previous variable.

In my opinion, I prefer `df.insert()` the most, for it allows you to assign which location you want to insert. (with parameter `loc`)

Comment: I tried making df = dataset and then df.assign(y_pred) but then I got this TypeError: assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Any idea why how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @zipline86 The format of `df.assign()` should be like `df.assign( _varname_ =content)`. You might want to check the link in the answer for more details.